# Why does my map activity return`'int android.database.Cursor.getCount()' on a null object reference`

Tags: android

Have a strange problem and can't find the solution. I have moved over from using eclipse to Android studio and the app was working fine in eclipse, but now in android studio is not.

Basically my app has a map with a data base in it to return data and save data.  So I re-written the app over in android studio, but now getting this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.database.Cursor.getCount()' on a null object reference
        at com.new.newapp.activity.FragmentGoogleMap.onLoadFinished(FragmentGoogleMap.java:436)
        at com.new.newapp.activity.FragmentGoogleMap.onLoadFinished(FragmentGoogleMap.java:67)
```

So at line 67 is this:

```
67 --> public class FragmentGoogleMap extends Fragment implements
        OnMapLongClickListener,
        LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>,
        OnMarkerClickListener,
        OnInfoWindowClickListener {
```

and then at line 436:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
        int locationCount;
        double lat= 0;
        double lng= 0;
        float zoom= 0;
        String title;
        String snippet;
        String id;
437 --> locationCount = arg1.getCount();
        arg1.moveToFirst();
```

Worth to mention:  Previously the class extended Activity,  now it is extending Fragment.

Can some-one please help.

**EDIT**

Cursor:

```
 map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MarkerInfoWindowAdapter());
    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

 .....

  @Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    Uri uri = LocationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI;
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uri, null, null, null, null);
}

 .....

  @Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
    getActivity();  //I added this but still doesn't work
    int locationCount;
    double lat= 0;
    double lng= 0;
    float zoom= 0;
    String title;
    String snippet;
    String id;
    locationCount = arg1.getCount();
    arg1.moveToFirst();

    for(int i=0;i<locationCount;i++){
        lat = arg1.getDouble(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_LAT));
        lng = arg1.getDouble(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_LNG));
        zoom = arg1.getFloat(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_ZOOM));
        title = arg1.getString(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_MTITLE));
        snippet = arg1.getString(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_MSNIPPET));
        id = arg1.getString(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_PICTURE));
        filepoint = arg1.getString(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_MFILEPATH));
        onPoint = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        createMarker(onPoint, title, snippet, id, filepoint);
        arg1.moveToNext();
    }
    if(locationCount>0){
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat,lng)));
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(zoom));
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
}
class LocationInsertTask extends AsyncTask<ContentValues, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(ContentValues... contentValues) {
        getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(LocationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, contentValues[0]);
        return null;
    }
}

private class LocationDeleteTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(LocationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null);
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Apparently your Cursor is the culprit can you post your code relative to that ?

Comment: Thanks for answering,  I have edited my question.

Comment: Did you try to run in debug mode ? What do you see for your Cursor object ? are the arguments good ?

Comment: sorry, I am not sure how to run in debug mode?

Comment: you set a breakpoint by clicking on the line numbers of your file. Once your are done Go to Run>Debug

Comment: Not seeing anything....

Answer (score 0):

It's just because your content provider `LocationsContentProvider` return `null` when query for the Uri `LocationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI`; 
Please recheck your content provider.

Also I found that your reveal code look a lot like in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27593421/how-to-save-extra-marker-data-to-sqlite-database).
If your code and that link are the same.
 
You should check all of this:

- `PROVIDER_NAME` match with `authorities` in manifest?
- `LocationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI` match with `UriMatcher` rule?
- there are any mistake in `query` method that can return `null`?

Comment: Do you add log in query method? the query uri, UriMatcher.match return? From your code above, that is the only place I think about now.

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: Well, I'm just curious about the `query` method of `LocationsContentProvider`. I think that is the cause of your issue.

Comment: The only difference is that I moved from `Activity` from eclipse to `fragment` android studio.  (redesigning app)